# How to fix recursive search through list

Tags: clojure

I'm currently trying to learn Clojure. But I am having trouble creating a function that recursively searches through each element of the list and returns the number of "a"'s present in the list.

I have already figured out how to do it iteratively, but I am having trouble doing it recursively. I have tried changing "seq" with "empty?" but that hasn't worked either.

---

```
(defn recursive-a [& lst]
 (if (seq lst)
     (if (= (first lst) "a")
         (+ 1 (recursive-a (pop (lst))))
         (+ 0 (recursive-a (pop (lst)))))
     0))
```

Comment: What's the problem? Is it an error pointing at `(lst)`? Why are you wrapping `lst` in parenthesis? The code works if you fix that, although I'd write it as something closer to [this](https://gist.github.com/carcigenicate/a415081ab8f07b3630ff185685313221) though. And `pop` isn't a good choice here as that's more for specific implementations. I changed it to use `rest` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stack overflow community.

You code is fine, except that you made a few minor mistakes.

Firstly, there is one extra pair of braces around your `lst` parameter that you forward to recursive function. In LISP languages, braces mean evaluation of function. So, first you should remove those.

Second thing is the `&` parameter syntactic sugar. You do not want to use that until you are certain how it affects your code.

With these changes, the code is as follows:

```
  (defn recursive-a [lst]
 (if (seq lst)
     (if (= (first lst) "a")
         (+ 1 (recursive-a (pop lst)))
         (+ 0 (recursive-a (pop lst))))
     0))


(recursive-a (list "a" "b" "c"))
```

You can run it in a web environment: https://repl.it/languages/clojure

Comment: You write *`"pop` ... returns a collection of type stack"*. It doesn't: `(type (pop (list 1 2))) => clojure.lang.PersistentList`; `(type (pop [1 2])) => clojure.lang.PersistentVector`. There is no stack **type** in Clojure. There is an underlying **interface** [`clojure.lang/IPersistentStack`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/IPersistentStack.java) that declares `peek` and `pop`.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

By invoking `recursive-a` explicitly the original implementation consumes stack with each recursion. If a sufficiently large list is provided as input this function will eventually exhaust the stack and crash. There are a several ways to work around this.

One of the classic Lisp-y methods for handling situations such as this is to provide a second implementation of the function which passes the running count as an input argument to the "inner" function:

```
(defn recursive-a-inner [cnt lst]
  (cond
    (seq lst) (cond
                (= (first lst) "a") (recur (inc cnt) (rest lst))
                :else               (recur cnt (rest lst)))
    :else cnt))

(defn recursive-a [& lst]
  (recursive-a-inner 0 lst))
```

By doing this the "inner" version allows the recursion to be pushed into tail position so that Clojure's `recur` keyword can be used. It's not quite as clean an implementation as the original but it has the advantage that it won't blow up the stack.

Another method for handling this is to use Clojure's `loop`-ing, which allows recursion within the body of a function. The result is much the same as the "inner" function above:

```
(defn recursive-a [& lp]
  (loop [cnt  0
         lst  lp]
    (cond
      (seq lst) (cond
                  (= (first lst) "a") (recur (inc cnt) (rest lst))
                  :else               (recur cnt (rest lst)))
      :else cnt)))
```

And if we drop the requirement for explicit recursion we can make this a bit simpler:

```
(defn not-recursive-a [& lst]
  (apply + (map #(if (= % "a") 1 0) lst)))
```

Best of luck.

Comment: I’d be inclined to go with (count (filter #(= "a" %) lst)) if we’re going to ignore the recursion

Comment: I agree, but for some reason I thought I'd seen that in an earlier answer or comment (which, apparently, I'd just imagined) so I thought I'd throw `map-reduce` (well, `map-apply` in this case :-) into the mix. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of learning:

You can use `&` or not.  Both are fine. The difference is how you would then call your function, and you would have to remember to use `apply` when recurring.

Also, simply use `first` and `rest`. They are both safe and will work on both nil and empty lists, returning nil and empty list respectively:

```clj
(first [])  ;; -> nil
(first nil) ;; -> nil
(rest [])   ;; -> ()
(rest nil)  ;; -> ()
```

So here is how I would re-work your idea:

```clj
;; With '&'
(defn count-a [& lst]
  (if-let [a (first lst)]
    (+ (if (= a "a") 1 0)
       (apply count-a (rest lst)))  ;; use 'apply' here
    0))
;; call with variable args, *not* a list
(count-a "a" "b" "a" "c") 

;; Without '&'
(defn count-a [lst]
  (if-let [a (first lst)]
    (+ (if (= a "a") 1 0)
       (count-a (rest lst)))
    0))
;; call with a single arg: a vector (could be a list or other )
(count-a ["a" "b" "a" "c"])
```

However, these are not safe, because they don't use tail-recursion, and so if your list is large, you will blow your stack!

So, we use `recur`.  But if you don't want to define an additional "helper" function, you can instead use `loop` as the "recur" target:

```clj
;; With '&'
(defn count-a [& lst]
  (loop [c 0  lst lst] ;; 'recur' will loop back to this point
    (if-let [a (first lst)]
      (recur (if (= a "a") (inc c) c) (rest lst))
      c)))
(count-a "a" "b" "a" "c")

;; Without '&'
(defn count-a [lst]
  (loop [c 0  lst lst]
    (if-let [a (first lst)]
      (recur (if (= a "a") (inc c) c) (rest lst))
      c)))
(count-a ["a" "b" "a" "c"])
```

All that being said, this is the one I also would use:

```clj
;; With '&'
(defn count-a [& lst]
  (count (filter #(= % "a") lst)))
(count-a "a" "b" "a" "c")

;; Without '&'
(defn count-a [lst]
  (count (filter #(= % "a") lst)))
(count-a ["a" "b" "a" "c"])
```